# JSON object iteration in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function in my React app that iterates a response array from a JSON API and it works fine with array `"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}]`:

```
render() {
    const persons = this.state.person.map((item) => {
       return <div>
       <h1>{item['id']}</h1>
       <span>{item['name']}</span>
       </div>
    }
}
```

But how to crate the same function but only for objects iteration? If `this.state.person` is something like this and I want to read `coord['lon']`:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Because of the `map` function it works only with array and I got this error:

```
this.state.person.map is not a function TypeError
```

**EDIT (add full code)**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {
      person: [],
        cityName: 'London'
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.UserList();
    }

    update(e){
      this.setState({cityName: e.target.value})
    }

  UserList(city = this.state.cityName){
      let weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=c24bda9c5812d6be82860b70c35d41a5';
    return $.getJSON(weatherURL).then((response) => {this.setState({person: response.coord})});
  }

    render() {
        const persons = this.state.person.map((item) => { // it gives me TypeError,
            return <div>
              <h1>{item[0]}</h1>
              <span>{item[1]}</span>
            </div>
        });

        return <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
          <input type="text"
          onChange={this.update.bind(this)}/>
          <div className="panel-list">{ persons }</div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default App;
```

It returns a `TypeError`, because of map function.

Comment: Use `person.wheather` then?

Comment: Please post a complete JSON representation of `this.state`. What you posted makes no sense - you claim to have an array in a `"wheather":` property but are accessing `this.state.person`?

Comment: @Bergi the problem in map, because `person: [ ]`, and `"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}` not an array as I understand

Comment: Didn't you say the first snippet with the map works fine?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `coord` object? Yes, you cannot iterate it. Just access `this.person.coord.lon`

Comment: @Bergi, yes if I write `return $.getJSON(weatherURL).then((response) => {this.setState({person: response.weather})});` It works fine because  `person: response.weather` it is array and map works, but if I want call to `"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}` it fails

Comment: I want just to show value of `coord.lon` it in my browser. How can I do this?

Comment: For that just `setState({coord: response.coord})` and render `this.state.coord.lon` (without any mapping). If you additionally want to show the wheather, do that with a separate `state` property

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! it works!

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the full response in state value, then access the specific property.

let say you stored complete response in variable `data`, then to access the `lon` value use `data.coord.lon`, and if you want `loop` over the weather the use it like this:

`data.weather.map(item => console.log(item.main))`

Check this example:

```js
let data = {
 "coord":{
  "lon":-0.13,
  "lat":51.51
 },
 "weather":[
  {
   "id":300,
   "main":"Drizzle",
   "description":"light intensity drizzle",
   "icon":"09d"
  }
 ],
 "base":"stations",
 "main":{
  "temp":280.32,
  "pressure":1012,
  "humidity":81,
  "temp_min":279.15,
  "temp_max":281.15
 },
 "visibility":10000,
 "wind":{
  "speed":4.1,
  "deg":80
 },
 "clouds":{
  "all":90
 },
 "dt":1485789600,
 "sys":{
  "type":1,
  "id":5091,
  "message":0.0103,
  "country":"GB",
  "sunrise":1485762037,
  "sunset":1485794875
 },
 "id":2643743,
 "name":"London",
 "cod":200
}

console.log('coord', data.coord.lon);

data.weather.map(item=>{
 console.log(item.main)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map over an arbitrary object, you should use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function. When called on an object, it will give you an array containing keys to all of the object's properties. You can then use `map` or `forEach` on this array in order to iterate over it.

For instance:

```
const person = this.state.person
const personKeys = Object.keys(person)

personKeys.map(key => do_something_with(key))
```